# Load json file into Asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, cocos2d-js

So, I'm trying to use [Cocos2d-JS](http://cocos2d-x.org/filecenter/jsbuilder/) to create a simple game embedded into one of my rails view.

The thing is that cocos requires a farly simple `project.json` file with some config data in it to run correctly, here's the internal code:

```
if(!txt){
    txt = cc.loader._loadTxtSync("project.json");
}
data = JSON.parse(txt);
```

Nonetheless even though I have this JSON file besides the cocos2d-JS .js file, I get always the same error running the rails server on development which is:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/project.json 404 (Not Found)
```

**What have I tried so far and haven't worked:**

1. Change the path on the js file to use a relative one, doesn't work.
2. Putting the JSON file in an aws bucket and try loading it from there, I get a non-authorized access error.
3. Renaming the `cocos2d.js` file to `cocos2d.js.erb` and lad the json with `<%= asset_path 'project.json' %>`, this breaks cocos2d itself...

**How to bypass in case I can't get an answer:**

I would try fixing the aws non authorized access issue, I'm a bit seasoned in Ruby and Rails, but don't fully understand the asset pipeline in order to find an alternative...

So my question is: Is this something related to the asset pipeline? How can I load this .json file into my js?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Just modified the CORS policy on aws to allow access from my web app and everything's done